# Getting indexPath of Parent Cell in Child TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parent-child

I currently have a TableView which is sitting inside a prototype TableViewCell. To remove confusion the hierarchy is as follows:

```
TableViewController
--> TableViewCell
    --> TableView
```

I am trying to access the indexPath.section in which the TableView is located, as for each different cell inside the TableViewController, I want to display different data in the TableView.

My code currently as follows:

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "todayCell", for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell

        // Configure the cell...
        switch indexPath.section {
        case 0:
            cell.label.text = "Today"
        case 1:
            cell.label.text = "Tomorrow"
        default:
            cell.label.text = "Error"
        }

        return cell
    }

}
```

For my TableViewCell:

```
class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var cancelButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var completeButton: UIButton!

    var numOfRowsOne = 6
    var numOfRowsTwo = 7



    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code


    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        var rows = 0
        if (TableViewController Cell's indexPath.section) == 0 {
            rows = numOfRowsOne
        } else {
            rows = numOfRowsTwo
        }

        return rows
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = todayTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "activitiesCell", for: indexPath)

        return cell
    }

 }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Just set a property on your cell so that it has the information it needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get `indexPath` as below,

```
if let ip = (self.superview as? UITableView)?.indexPath(for: self), ip.section == 0 {
    rows = numOfRowsOne
} else {
    rows = numOfRowsTwo
}
```